# Check narrowing floating point conversions

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point

In some code I'm working on there is a (narrowing) conversion from `double` to `float`.  The legacy code has some checks in place after the conversion is done to at least warn about values that could not be converted or whose conversion error is larger than some threshold (0.1 for example).  Just for comparison:

```
float target = source; // decltype(source) == double
if (std::abs(source) < 1e16) {
  if (std::abs(target) > 1e16) {
    // WARNING
  }
} else if (abs(target/source - 1) > 1e16) {
  // WARNING
}
```

This code lies directly on the (most) critical path, and felt very inelegant (and wrong?) to me, so I tried to improve it. *Note that I don't intend to replicate the exact same behavior as the legacy code*.

```
if (!representable_with_digits_after_point_in<float>(source, 3)) {
  // WARNING
}
float target = source;
```

With the following (templated) function:

```
/** Check whether the given value can be represented in the Target
    type with at least given number of (binary) digits after point.
 */
template <class Target, class Value>
bool representable_with_digits_after_point_in(Value const value,
                                              int digits) {
  static_assert(std::is_floating_point<Value>::value
                && std::is_floating_point<Target>::value,
                "Intended to be used with floating point types");
  using limits = std::numeric_limits<Target>;
  int exponent;
  static_cast<void>(std::frexp(value, &exponent));
  if (exponent > limits::max_exponent
      || (limits::digits - exponent) < digits) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

I'm pretty sure (though I haven't measured yet) that my version is a lot faster than the legacy one *on one of the target platforms which doesn't have hardware floating point support*.  I'm also guessing that on the other platforms the actual speed difference will be negligible.

**What I'm more concerned about:** Do I correctly detect all circumstances where the conversion result will be +/- Infinity (when the source is not) and where the conversion error (`abs(static_cast<double>(target) - source)` so to say) will be more than `2^(-digits)` (`digits = 3` in my example call above)?

Apart from that, any other suggestions on how to improve my code? Other ways to get the job done *without* any floating point arithmetic?

Comment: I believe the only thing you need to do is compare `std::epsilon`s and check if source is in range of target's representable range by checking against `std::max` and std::`min`. If I understood the problem definition correctly it should be enough.

Comment: @Incomputable I'd like to avoid floating point operations as much as possible. Comparing floating point values is not trivial when there's no hardware doing that around. The `std::numeric_limits::epsilon` unfortunately doesn't help. The digits after point that can be stored depend on the number. A `double` can store `2097152.125` whereas a `float` can only store `2097152` and as next value `2097152.25`. The `0.125` (= `2^-(3)`) cannot be hold because `2097152` (= `2^22`) needs 22 (binary) digits to be stored, thus a `float` with 24 available digits has then only 2 let to store fractions.